# How to ensure that formatoptions *never* contains `r` or `o`?

Tags: vim

In **vim**, the filetype occasionally is set to a value that auto-populates formatoptions with `r` and `o`, two features that I do not like.  What setting can I add to guarantee that under no circumstances will those characters appear in formatoptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying @sergio's answer slightly, 
you could use

```
autocmd Filetype * set fo-=r fo-=o
```

in your vimrc.

This removes 'r' and 'o' from 'formatoptions' whenever the filetype is set.

(Note that filetype detection has to be on, which can be set by `:filetype on`.)

Answer (score 3):

You could define an auto-command in ~/.vimrc to remove `r` and `o` format options from every file type:

```
autocmd CmdLineLeave,BufEnter * set fo-=r fo-=o
```

Comment: This works if I leave and re-enter the buffer.  But if I just do `:set ft=conf`, the settings are in `formatoptions` until I re-enter.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Does it work in `autocmd FileType`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell in that case you could use `CmdLineLeave` event as in my updated answer. The various auto command events are listed in  `:help auto*abc`

Comment: I think I may have mis-phrased the question, and unintentionally limited the scope.  I'm going to ask a different question, and throw a bone to bert for the accepted answer, since FileType does seem more appropriate for this question as asked.  Thanks for the CmdLineLeave enter suggestion, as that does seem to be effective.