# Is it possible to fix options in vim?

Tags: vim

Following up on [How to ensure that formatoptions *never* contains `r` or `o`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277539/how-to-ensure-that-formatoptions-never-contains-r-or-o/59279516#59279516), which was poorly phrased.

Is it possible in vim to assign options in such a way that they cannot be modified by plugins or startup scripts.  For example, something like:

```
set const final opt=value
```

in .vimrc would be great.  I imagine this would be an error if opt is already constant, causing vim to refuse to open the buffer it is initializing when it encounters this, or possibly even exiting.

Does such a feature currently exist?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. There are both `:const` and `:lockvar`, but they are for variables only. An option is a very different thing for VimScript.

However, you can fake this functionality with an auto-command. For example,

```
augroup ForbidSetOptions | au!
    autocmd OptionSet formatoptions
        \ if &filetype ==# 'foo'
            \ echom 'You are not allowed to "set fo" for "foo" files!'
            \ set formatoptions=jcroql
        \ endif
augroup end
```

Note that we don't fall into an infinite recursion, because an auto-command is not triggered from another auto-command by default.

But note that this event is intentionally NOT triggered on startup. So you probably should consult a relevant plugin documentation instead to setup the options the way you want. Or write your own `~/.vim/after/plugin/...` (or `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/...`) script to undo such undesirable settings automatically.