# How to start a new line with "o" without duplicating quotation mark?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a bit of a weird problem. I place my cursor on line 9 (" turn on visualization ...), then press "o", and it inserts a new line below but with the quotation mark instead of being blank. Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ensure that formatoptions \*never\* contains \`r\` or \`o\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277539/how-to-ensure-that-formatoptions-never-contains-r-or-o)

Comment: yeah that helped

Answer (score 2):

" Edit the file (if not exists create it):

```
nvim ~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/vim.vim
```

And its content:

```
" ~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/vim.vim
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
  finish
endif
" Don't load another plugin for this buffer
let b:did_ftplugin = 1

setlocal ft=vim
setlocal formatoptions-=cro
```

The important line is `setlocal formatoptions-=cro` but if you put this directly on your `init.vim` all auto comments for any language will be disabled. This also gives you the ability to create more specific settings for specific filetypes.

The "`if`" part makes sure that the current file loads once, discarding other ftplugins for the same filetype

OBS: There is another way to set `ftplugins` as they are called, and it changes the order in wich they are loaded, if you put your file on: `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin` the settings will be loaded **after** the system settings.

**Another tip**: If you are in normal mode and press `o` to create a new line and if your settings are defined to create automatic comments you can simple press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> to erase until the begining of the line.

Comment: Setting the filetype in an ftplugin is unecessary. The after directory is generally preferably